# Identifying a function

Tags: special-functions

I am reading a piece of a physic paper where a function is mentioned without being given a name or reference - I guess it is a canonical one and that I should be familiar with.

The expression goes as:

$$|_2F_1(a,b;c;z)|$$

with $a,b,c \in {\mathbb R}$ and $z \in {\mathbb C}$. Also I am fairly sure the lowerscript 2 is a label on the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Another source would be http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html.

Answer (score 1):

> In mathematics, the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function
>   2F1(a,b;c;z) is a special function represented by the hypergeometric
>   series, that includes many other special functions as specific or
>   limiting cases. It is a solution of a second-order linear ordinary
>   differential equation (ODE). Every second-order linear ODE with three
>   regular singular points can be transformed into this equation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function